# How can I get the value of item.value.key

Tags: ansible

I have a dictionary like this:

```
list_of_dicts:
  config:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
```

When I loop the dictionary I want to combine key/value pair.

```
set_facts:
  list_of_dicts: {{ list_of_dicts | default({}) | combine (item.key: item.value) }}
with_dict: "{{ list_of_dicts }}"
```

How can I get the value of item.value.key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the filter_plugin below (credit [Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/rxsmvw/iterating-a-hash-in-an-ansible-task))

```
> cat filter_plugins/hash_utils.py
def hash_to_tuples(h):
    return h.items()

def hash_keys(h):
    return h.keys()

def hash_values(h):
    return h.values()

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' utility filters for operating on hashes '''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'hash_to_tuples' : hash_to_tuples
            ,'hash_keys'     : hash_keys
            ,'hash_values'   : hash_values
        }
```

The play

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item|hash_keys }}"
  loop:  "{{ list_of_dicts.values() }}"
```

gives (abridged):

```
    "msg": [
    "key2", 
    "key1"
]
```

You might want to try *hash_to_tuples* and *hash_values* filters.